# Is there a SQLite row size restriction like mySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite

In mysql there is a hard limit of row size of 65,535 bytes which I believe is based of page size. Is there a similar restriction with Sqlite3?

I tried reading through https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html on the Sqlite site but found no specific indication there is. But then I am not a DB expert so maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limits page you link to says this:

> During part of SQLite's INSERT and SELECT processing, the complete content of each row in the database is encoded as a single BLOB. So the SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH parameter also determines the **maximum number of bytes in a row.**

(emphasis mine)

So `SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH` is the maximum length of a row, including any BLOB values.

The default is 1000000000 bytes.

---

For what it's worth, the row length limit in MySQL of 65535 bytes does *not* apply to BLOB/TEXT columns. And it has nothing to do with page size.

Comment: Wow, right there in the first paragraph. gotta read more carefully.